# syntax error on .foreach statement

Tags: windbg

I have a .dmp for a pool leak case and I've identified the tag that is causing the problem but there are a lot of modules loaded for that tag. I'm trying to script using eb in WinDBG to edit the module names so that I can identify which is which. I've tried a bunch of different takes on this statement and I cannot get it to do exactly what I want which is to iterate through all modules related to the pool tag and rename them by replacing the last letter of the tag with a number.

```
.block {r @$t0=0x31; !for_each_module .foreach( obj {s -[1]a @#Base @#End "FMfn"}){r @$t0 = @$t0+1; eb ${obj}+3 @$t0}}
```

This is the latest error I'm receiving

```
@$t0+1'
                                                                    ^ Syntax error in '.foreach( obj {s -[1]a fffff96000925000 fffff9600095f000 "FMfn"}){r @$t0 = @$t0+1'
Couldn't resolve error at '${obj}+3 $t0}'
```

Can anyone help me identify where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the documentation, `!for_each_module` needs quotation marks around the command string:

```
!for_each_module ["CommandString"]
```

and according to my tests they don't seem to be optional, so add the quotation marks and escape existing quotation marks like this:

```
.block {r @$t0=0x31; !for_each_module ".foreach( obj {s -[1]a @#Base @#End \"FMfn\"}){r @$t0 = @$t0+1; eb ${obj}+3 @$t0}"}
```